# Cannot Install Meteor on command line Mac OSX

Tags: macos, curl, meteor, sh

I'm trying to install Meteor on my Mac, following the instructions on their site (https://www.meteor.com/install)

```
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

However, when I run the command, I get the following error:

```
sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
sh: line 1: `<!DOCTYPE html>'
```

Pretty new to Terminal, so pointers appreciated.

Comment: what does curl `curl https://install.meteor.com/` return?

Comment: It returns the install script

Comment: I've installed it now, dowloading the script manually, but still curious as to why this didn't work

Comment: Does the error show immediately after you call that command? If so, does `curl -s https://install.meteor.com/ | head -n1` return `#!/bin/bash`? _The `-s` flag hides the progress meter and the `|` (pipe) into `head` shows the beginning of a file. `-n1` makes `head` only show the first line._

Comment: yes it returns #!/bin/bash

Comment: looks to me like you weren't really online at first, but got served some sort of log-in screen when you tried it at first. I could imagine that it would work if you tried again now.